# Access to Alfresco REST APIs

Tags: rest, alfresco

Are the Alfresco REST APIs only available when running in the cloud or can I use them with our inhouse install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alfresco exposes a number of different REST-like APIs. The one you probably refer to is the latest [Cloud API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_API) which is indeed only available for Cloud instances.

There are also a number of other REST APIs that are always present in each and every installation of Alfresco, local installs included. Assuming you installed Alfresco locally, and that it responds to `http://localhost:8080/alfresco`, you can browse all the available REST APIs by going to"

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index
```

EDIT: you need admin rights to access that URL. If you are not an admin of that instance, you can have an idea of which kind of APIs you get access to by visiting

```
http://cmis.alfresco.com/service/index
```

The credentials will be `admin:admin`. That instance runs Alfresco 4.0.0 Community.

Comment: When I try to hit http://cms.ejiw.com:8080/alfresco/service/index I get a 401 unauthorized error -  01040011 Web Script org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/index.get requires admin authentication; however, a non-admin has attempted access.

Comment: indeed, you need to authenticate yourself as an admin to reach that URL, I'll update the answer

Comment: Interesting...  When I hit cms.alfresco.com/service/index it asks for a username and password.  But when I hit our copy at cms.ejiw.com/service/index it does not, it just gives me the 401.  At least this gives me some direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Please note a couple of things. First, the Public API which is currently only available in the cloud will eventually also be available on-premise. This API is comprised of CMIS plus a RESTful JSON-based API for things that CMIS does not cover. Second, skuro is correct that there are many out-of-the-box web scripts and he tells you how to find them, but just understand that unless a web script explicitly says it is public, it may change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need admin-rights. By default on installation, an admin user is created (normally 'admin'). Please contact installaer/administrators of server (cms.ejiw.com)

Alternatively download source and find the URLs in the webscripts or install your local community edition for development